# r function to compare values for successive levels of a factor for each column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing data for 9 variables, each measured at 7 sites (A-G) under several different conditions.

```
    my.df <- structure(list(Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Cond1", "Cond2", "Cond3", 
"Cond4", "Cond5", "Cond6", "Cond7", "Cond8"), class = "factor"), 
    Site = structure(c(6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
    5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"
    ), class = "factor"), Variable1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.00333333333333333, 0, 0.00333333333333333, 0.0233333333333333, 
    0.02, 0, 0.00333333333333333, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0.03, 
    0.376666666666667, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0, 
    0.256666666666667, 0.16), Variable2 = c(0.04, 0.0233333333333333, 
    0.0466666666666667, 0.256666666666667, 0.02, 0.07, 0.48, 
    0.0466666666666667, 0.0766666666666667, 0.0266666666666667, 
    0.08, 0.04, 0.136666666666667, 0.15, 0.433333333333333, 0.16, 
    1.69666666666667, 0.14, 1.99666666666667, 3.66, 3.18, 0.04, 
    0.0633333333333333, 0.446666666666667, 0.0733333333333333, 
    0.54, 1.83666666666667, 2.01), Variable3 = c(7.64333333333333, 
    5.16333333333333, 16.84, 2.52333333333333, 1.35333333333333, 
    27.2666666666667, 17.36, 1.48666666666667, 0.596666666666667, 
    8.07333333333333, 4.77, 3.4, 6.86666666666667, 4.26, 23.6466666666667, 
    16.87, 42.1766666666667, 20.23, 33.03, 52.37, 50.46, 9.19333333333333, 
    5.09, 13.6833333333333, 11.4566666666667, 16.1133333333333, 
    26.59, 23.76), Variable4 = c(1.86333333333333, 1.41666666666667, 
    0.263333333333333, 0.953333333333333, 0.28, 0.323333333333333, 
    0.28, 1.85, 1.43666666666667, 1.16, 1.28, 2.48, 3.49666666666667, 
    3.79, 15.96, 16.6466666666667, 16.8166666666667, 10.0933333333333, 
    16.9666666666667, 17.5633333333333, 19.83, 6.61, 6.20333333333333, 
    5.72, 5.13, 6.78333333333333, 8.94333333333333, 9.66), Variable5 = c(23.84, 
    23.91, 14.11, 18.5633333333333, 16.8933333333333, 9.37, 11.34, 
    33.63, 35.4633333333333, 24.04, 32.3066666666667, 20.8166666666667, 
    25.4466666666667, 25.14, 24.33, 24.9766666666667, 10.5966666666667, 
    17.4333333333333, 12.99, 10.1133333333333, 10.18, 33.9166666666667, 
    32.3433333333333, 18.3666666666667, 25.8766666666667, 17.7633333333333, 
    18.7466666666667, 18.71), Variable6 = c(7.47333333333333, 
    8.04, 16.4033333333333, 17.1866666666667, 16.5533333333333, 
    3.82666666666667, 4.39, 28.6466666666667, 37.14, 27.23, 35.54, 
    17.47, 17.84, 16.43, 10.5, 14.88, 6.04, 16.45, 8.90333333333333, 
    3.75666666666667, 3.55, 32.4533333333333, 28.2366666666667, 
    17.36, 26.2766666666667, 14.5266666666667, 11.9766666666667, 
    11.11), Variable7 = c(21.6933333333333, 21.27, 8.95666666666667, 
    15.73, 9.61333333333333, 14.9166666666667, 18.07, 18.43, 
    12.0466666666667, 13.7433333333333, 9.78, 25.76, 27.4066666666667, 
    31.42, 10.4966666666667, 8.57, 8.59333333333333, 8.36, 7.97333333333333, 
    6.08, 7.03, 7.28333333333333, 11.82, 19.3533333333333, 10.1366666666667, 
    19.27, 18.9833333333333, 21.19), Variable8 = c(19.4866666666667, 
    19.9766666666667, 25.7, 21.1966666666667, 38.0266666666667, 
    36.04, 40.49, 2.54666666666667, 1.83, 11.0133333333333, 3.76, 
    13.5633333333333, 5.42, 6.16, 4.58666666666667, 5.75333333333333, 
    8.76666666666667, 13.52, 10.41, 3.95666666666667, 4.56, 1.51, 
    3.45333333333333, 12.2333333333333, 6.62333333333333, 11.9566666666667, 
    4.67, 5.18), Variable9 = c(17.97, 20.1866666666667, 17.6633333333333, 
    23.61, 17.27, 8.18, 7.6, 13.3533333333333, 11.3933333333333, 
    14.7, 12.48, 16.4766666666667, 13.3666666666667, 12.64, 10.07, 
    12.1466666666667, 5.30666666666667, 13.78, 7.7, 2.13333333333333, 
    1.12, 8.98, 12.79, 12.83, 14.4133333333333, 13.0433333333333, 
    8.00666666666667, 8.23)), .Names = c("Condition", "Site", 
"Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable5", 
"Variable6", "Variable7", "Variable8", "Variable9"), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, for each variable and under each condition, I want to compare the values at each successive site (A through G).  If the value of x is larger at site B than at site A, I want to replace the site B value with the site A value.  Also, I'd like to create another column Y, and put in Y the difference between x at B and x at A (assuming B>A).

Then I want to go on and do the same comparison for sites B and C (if C>B, replace C with B, and put the difference in column Y). And after comparing the values at all the sites, go on and do the same thing for each variable under each condition.

I'd like to write a function to automatically do all these comparisons for me. I can use lapply to run the function over the `colnames` (to run it for each variable), and I think I can use `ave` (inside the lapply call) to run my inner function over subsets of "Condition".  The logical arguments are quite simple, but I don't know how to call the values of successive levels of a factor (Sites A through G).  Basically, the inner function (called by `ave` inside `lapply`) would be something like this: 
EDIT:  maybe I was I rethinking things and don't need the 'lapply', and could just use 'by' instead...but the problem remains

```
 for(i in 1:length(levels(my.df$Site)){
   if(levels(my.df$Site)[i+1] > levels(my.df$Site)[i]) {
     print(levels(my.df$Site)[i])  
     #But this isn't right, because I want the *value*, not the factor
   }
 })
```

There must be a way to do this; any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: In the successive comparisons between the sites, should the starting values be used or -for example- in case B's value is replaced by A's, then the comparison between B and C is made with the new value of B?

Comment: Yes; the idea is that, at each successive site, the value of the observation can decrease (and the difference be added to column Y), but never increase.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. When you'll come to compare B and C, will the starting value of B be used or the new value of B (assuming it has been replaced by A, because it was larger than A's)?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give this a shot, although I'm not sure I fully understood the question.

Since you want to apply a function to every combination of "Condition" and "Variable", I thought you could turn `my.df` to a long format, split at each "cond ~ var" and apply a function. The following assumes that there is *only one* "Site" for every "cond ~ var". I hope that you'll find something helpful in this:

```
my_long_df = reshape(my.df, direction = "long", 
                     idvar = c("Condition", "Site"), 
                     varying = list(3:11),
                     timevar = "Variable", v.names = "value")

spl_ldf = split(my_long_df, 
                 interaction(my_long_df$Condition, my_long_df$Variable, drop = T))

ff = function(x) {
  x = x[match(levels(my.df$Site), x$Site), ]
  x$Y = c(NA, diff(x$value))
  valT = head(x$value, -1)
  valF = x$value[-1]
  x$newvals = c(NA, ifelse(x$Y[-1] > 0, valT, valF))  
  return(x)
}
res = do.call(rbind, lapply(spl_ldf, ff))
res[29:49, ]  #just a subset of the output
#                  Condition Site Variable      value           Y    newvals
#Cond1.2.Cond1.A.2     Cond1    A        2 0.48000000          NA         NA
#Cond1.2.Cond1.B.2     Cond1    B        2 0.07000000 -0.41000000 0.07000000
#Cond1.2.Cond1.C.2     Cond1    C        2 0.04666667 -0.02333333 0.04666667
#Cond1.2.Cond1.D.2     Cond1    D        2 0.02000000 -0.02666667 0.02000000
#Cond1.2.Cond1.E.2     Cond1    E        2 0.25666667  0.23666667 0.02000000
#Cond1.2.Cond1.F.2     Cond1    F        2 0.04000000 -0.21666667 0.04000000
#Cond1.2.Cond1.G.2     Cond1    G        2 0.02333333 -0.01666667 0.02333333
#Cond2.2.Cond2.A.2     Cond2    A        2 0.15000000          NA         NA
#Cond2.2.Cond2.B.2     Cond2    B        2 0.13666667 -0.01333333 0.13666667
#Cond2.2.Cond2.C.2     Cond2    C        2 0.02666667 -0.11000000 0.02666667
#Cond2.2.Cond2.D.2     Cond2    D        2 0.04000000  0.01333333 0.02666667
#Cond2.2.Cond2.E.2     Cond2    E        2 0.08000000  0.04000000 0.04000000
#Cond2.2.Cond2.F.2     Cond2    F        2 0.04666667 -0.03333333 0.04666667
#Cond2.2.Cond2.G.2     Cond2    G        2 0.07666667  0.03000000 0.04666667
#Cond3.2.Cond3.A.2     Cond3    A        2 3.18000000          NA         NA
#Cond3.2.Cond3.B.2     Cond3    B        2 3.66000000  0.48000000 3.18000000
#Cond3.2.Cond3.C.2     Cond3    C        2 1.69666667 -1.96333333 1.69666667
#Cond3.2.Cond3.D.2     Cond3    D        2 1.99666667  0.30000000 1.69666667
#Cond3.2.Cond3.E.2     Cond3    E        2 0.14000000 -1.85666667 0.14000000
#Cond3.2.Cond3.F.2     Cond3    F        2 0.43333333  0.29333333 0.14000000
#Cond3.2.Cond3.G.2     Cond3    G        2 0.16000000 -0.27333333 0.16000000
```